# Google APIs console and dashboard show different projects

Tags: google-app-engine, dashboard

I work from a laptop or a desktop, depending where I am.  I recently created two app-engine projects, no issues on either machine.  I created and deployed a third using a laptop, which shows-up on  https://code.google.com/apis/console.

Switching back to the original desktop machine, with all the files copied across, this third project is unusable ("does not exist") from the App Engine Launcher.  Looking at https://appengine.google.com/dashboard the third project is not there.

I created and deployed a fourth project which is fine and appears in both.  All I did was to use the project 3 files, change the application name in app.yaml and Add Existing Application.

So https://code.google.com/apis/console dashboard shows all 4 projects, https://appengine.google.com/dashboard only shows 3 (1,2,4).

My guess is that the App Engine Launcher does not get refreshed from the web.  I copied all files from laptop to desktop, but perhaps I missed some.  Any ideas?

I am using Windows 7 on both machines, and not using Eclipse (just a text editor).

Answer (score 0):

The App Engine Launcher does not do automatic synching of any sort.  Yes, you can deploy your project to the App Engine servers, but it doesn't automatically pull projects down.

You just need to use Add Existing Project to add project 3 to your App Engine Launcher on your desktop.

Keep in mind that if you update the app from one machine, you will need to manually synch your codebase on the other machine.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that.  I did "Add Existing Project", but I still get the inconsistency.